# How can I download a layer from a website map based on the google mymaps?

Tags: google-maps, kml

On this website https://www.magticom.ge/en/useful-info/offices you see a map with a layers (4.5G, 4G, 3G and 2G) that are uploaded in Google Mymaps, I asked the company if they can give these layers but operators have no idea about that. Now I have to find other ways to get the layers for my GIS. Is there any possibility?

Comment: The map on that site does not look like it's generated from a simple Google MyMap. It looks like a custom Google Maps API implementation which loads the data on the map from a JSON list embedded in a script on the page.  If you look at the page's source code, you should be able to find it after the line that starts with: "var offices = ...". You can try to extract it from there, or ask the company if they are willing to share the data in an easier format like a spreadsheet or KML file.  [Edit: just noticed the answers already referred to this... apologies for duplication].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, some quick hacking and I found they are just georeferenced KML images.

The KML file has bounding coordinates and calls the png image.

https://www.magticom.ge/services/coverage/3g.kml
https://www.magticom.ge/services/coverage/3g.png

I would expect to see 2g, 3g, and 4.5g  KML and PNG images from similar urls.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut 
Look for "Ground Overlays" to understand these KML files.

Comment: When I saw 4g.png in the txt I thought the same that this png must be somewhere near :) you found them faster. Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: What "hacking" did you do to find the original KML files?

Answer (score 0):

It's JSON data in the HTML page. Right click on the page View Source. Search for "var offices = JSON.parse( " and the data starts here. it is just JSON, it runs until you find "// Offices"

I copied it into https://jsonlint.com/ and here is an example.

```
{
    "id": "48",
    "slug": "akhalkalaki",
    "justice_center": "0",
    "br_service": "0",
    "manager_mobile": "",
    "deputy_mobile": "",
    "manager_email": "",
    "deputy_email": "",
    "capital": "0",
    "city": "Akhalkalaki",
    "address": "41\/2 Tavisuplebis St.",
    "work_on_workdays": "1",
    "work_on_saturday": "1",
    "work_on_sunday": "0",
    "working_hours_on_workdays": "09:00-18:00",
    "working_hours_on_weekend": "10:00-17:00",
    "break_hours_on_workdays": "13:00-14:00",
    "break_hours_on_weekend": "",
    "coordinates": "41.40961155684,43.484676944965"
}
```

You could convert it or parse it into what ever format you need.

Comment: Thanks @BillChappell for your attention, what you say it is about point data, but I want polygon layers, click 4G or 3G above the map it will show polygon.

Comment: At the moment what I find out that when you click 4G in the code section appears code: 

'<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/KmlOverlayService.GetOverlays?1shttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.magticom.ge%2Fservices%2Fcoverage%2F4g.kml%3Fv%3D7&amp;callback=_xdc_._n63scg&amp;token=102665"></script>'

from this url I found KML link but in Google Earth it appears empty: https://www.magticom.ge/services/coverage/4g.kml

Comment: open the kml in a text editor, to see image reference and coordinates.

Comment: It shows this, but how can I use it in ArcMap?

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0"><GroundOverlay><name> MapInfo Saved View</name><visibility>1</visibility><Icon><href>4g.png</href></Icon><LatLonBox><north>43.2336</north><south>41.0368</south><east>46.724</east><west>41.2728</west><rotation>0</rotation></LatLonBox></GroundOverlay></kml>

Comment: To use in ArcMap, Toolbox, Conversion tools/KLM to Layer, and make sure you check "Include Ground Overlay". If you bring it in later under RGB the image has Band_4 as Alpha and stretch = None.